Invocation of mocked function isn't registered properly when using default mock
I have the problem that a mocked function (from jest.fn()) gets invoked but that invocation isn't registered properly. I found other ppl. having the same problem when they're forgot to await an async call, but I don't really see how that applies in my case.
This is my test:
import { render,screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { default as userEvent } from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { signIn } from 'hooks/__mocks__/auth';
import { LoginButton } from './LoginButton';

jest.mock('hooks/auth');

describe('<LoginButton />', () => {
  beforeEach(()=>render(<LoginButton />));
  it('should trigger the sign-in process on click', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }));
    console.log("clicked") // This is the second entry I see logged
    expect(signIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Error: received number of calls: 0
  });
});

The component is just:
export const LoginButton: React.FC = () => {
  const signIn = useSignIn();
  return (
    <Button color="secondary" onClick={signIn}>
      Login
    </Button>
  );
};

and the mocked methods look like that:
export const signIn = jest.fn();
export const useSignIn = () => ()=>{
  console.log('signIn'); // This is the first entry I see logged
  signIn()
};

I see "signIn"  before "clicked, so I don't think it's a race condition/a missing await. If I replace console.log("clicked") with signIn(), the test succeeds.
No warnings or errors are logged (besides the failing expect ofc).
Update
Putting that at the top of the test file works, though.
const signIn = jest.fn();
jest.mock('hooks/auth', ()=>({
  useSignIn:() => () =>{
    console.log('signIn');
    signIn()
  }
}));

So I just can't use the default mock. I'm more confused then ever.

You can use mockFn.mock.results to get the signIn mock function from mock useSignIn() hook.
e.g.
hooks/auth.ts:
export const useSignIn = () => {
  return () => {
    console.log('sign in real implementation');
  };
};

hooks/__mocks__/auth.ts:
export const signIn = jest.fn(() => console.log('mock signIn called'));
export const useSignIn = jest.fn(() => signIn);

LoginButton.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { useSignIn } from './hooks/auth';

export const LoginButton: React.FC = () => {
  const signIn = useSignIn();
  return <button onClick={signIn}>Login</button>;
};

LoginButton.test.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { useSignIn } from './hooks/auth';
import { LoginButton } from './LoginButton';

jest.mock('./hooks/auth');

const useSignInMock = jest.mocked(useSignIn);

describe('<LoginButton />', () => {
  beforeEach(() => render(<LoginButton />));
  it('should trigger the sign-in process on click', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' }));
    const signIn = useSignInMock.mock.results[0].value;
    expect(signIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});

Test result:
  console.log
    mock signIn called

      at log (stackoverflow/78483774/hooks/__mocks__/auth.ts:1:45)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78483774/LoginButton.test.tsx
  <LoginButton />
    √ should trigger the sign-in process on click (102 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------                                                                                                                                                                           
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                                                                                                                                            
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 LoginButton.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.197 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.


Hey, thank you for the reply! The problem is, I don't want to check that useSignIn got invoked, but the signIn (mock) function returned by that hook useSignIn. The weird thing is that it works when set up a new useSignIn mock right in the test file, and returning a signIn (from jest.fn()) declared in the test file itself, but not when with useSignIn and the returned signIn function from my __mocks__.

@NotX The test above is check the signIn function returned by useSignIn hook.

I see, then I misinterpreted what this line useSignInMock.mock.results[0].value does. That said, useSignInMock.mock is undefined. I tried to remove useSignIn from __mocks__ to avoid weird collisions (but I kept jest.mock('hooks/auth'); const useSignInMock = jest.mocked(useSignIn);), but this mocking fails with [TypeError: (0 , _auth.useSignIn) is not a function. So that's probably it.
